# Is there any way to make a config file "interactive"?

Tags: config

I am working with a config file from Python that, depending on the configuration, some variables should not be filled (adding values to these variables will have no effect).

I was wondering if there is an easy and clean way to make an "interactive" config file. With this I mean, I would like to make a configuration application that, for example, shows some new variables to be filled, depending on a previously given value, or even limits the input values with sliders.

I have searched for something like this, but I haven't found anything. Is there any way to make the config files more "interactive" (preferably Python-based)?

Comment: This is an already solved problem, there are tools such as [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) to handle configuration. The "interactiveness portion is something you should implement by yourself based on the requirements.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, indeed I'm using configparser. However, I was wondering if there is any way to make a config file in a format different than plain text (.ini), so a user can configure the application in a more "user-friendly" way (and dependant on the actual configuration of some values).